# Whats the best way to encode form data?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, serialization

I'm still struggling with this mystery.  Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thetoolsmith/V4ftf/) The serialized data is getting sent to my php function like so:

```
headline:I'm+still+here!
```

I need the data to look like this:

```
headline:I%27m+still+here%21
```

Do I need to call the replace method on my serialized data and just convert the single quotes or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to escape `'`s?  The apostrophe is a valid character in URLs according to [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).  Presumably, that is why jQuery is not escaping it for you.

If you must escape it for some reason, then yes - use the `replace` method.

Comment: If I send it to my php function and use mysql_real_escape_string($headline) it looks like this when returned from the DB: I\'m still here!

Comment: That is how it should look.  The `\'` sequence tells mySQL that the `'` is not SQL syntax, it's merely part of the contents of some data you are passing to MySQL.

Comment: How then do I prevent it from adding it to the DB like that?

Comment: The backslash will not appear in the database.  Please read this tutorial to get a better understanding of what is going on and how the pieces fit together: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing but using mysql_real_escape_string() is adding this to my DB: first update: I\'m still here!
 second update: I\\\'m still here!

Comment: @cheeken he said thats how it gets RETURNED from the db, meaning his request data is getting double escaped before being placed into the DB...

Comment: @Paul, chances are you have PHP magic quotes turned on in your php configuration. magic quotes attempts to automatically escape all request data, then you are re escapiong it again with mysql function. you will want to turn off magic quotes as they are not safe to use to escape mysql content, or strip slashes before using the mysql function.

Comment: wow...that was my issue, I had magic quotes on.  turning them off solved all my issues!  Thanks for the help.